# А есть русские каналы IRC с iOS Developers в нашем комьюнити?

Tags: objective-c, ios, apple

Собственно сабж.. Ну и мак девелоперс тоже.

Comment: Есть скайп-чятик, на счет irc - хз, не встречал

Comment: я просто, нечаянно, подумал может создать такой

Comment: Помнится были попытки, если создадите - маякуйте здесь

Comment: Да я погуглю эту тему... и отпишусь

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.

Comment: @PeterOlson вопрос мигрировал с ХешКод`а, так что может быть закрыт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока русское комьюнити сидит:

- Skype: skype:?chat&blob=lqEUPiqbVpyG-7jUy1TtdwAimPNDkWMlbT5APkMu1dXmA2zxj7sDgF077ON8jksKP6u-0rMyGm4
- Facebook groops: [Cocoaheads](https://www.facebook.com/cocoaheadsmsk?fref=ts)
- [Slack сообщенство](http://ios-developers.ru/)

P.S. что еще найду буду дополнятьэтот список

Answer (score -1):

IRC артефакт из 90х. Есть вк группа, там активно. Поиск по objective-c developer.

Comment: Расмусы Лердорфы срочно покидают свои безнадежно устаревшие mailing lists и irc и срочно бегут регистрировать профили в соцсеточке

Comment: Настолько толсто, что даже тонко. Снимаю шляпу.

Comment: Меня в вк пожизнено заблокировало. Мол я взламывал какие-то игры, ладно бы я в ней что-либо делал. По этому в топку эту глупую соц сеть. А IRC хоть и артефакт, но настолько стабилен, что не сравнится со всякими контактами и скайпами.

Comment: @Bimawa, хорошо, Расмусы Лердорфы срочно и массово деактивируют свои аккаунты в соцсеточке, потому что с вами там что-то не до конца объясненное произошло.

Comment: Да на самом деле я не против соц сеточек, просто есть потребность, хз как ее удовлетворить лучшим способом.